# Is there any way to check if CUDA is available and set environment variables if so?

Tags: bash

I have a Python program that I use for machine learning stuff. I want to run this using a Shell script and I sometimes set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` in order to use NVIDIA GPUs.

I want to run the same program on my M1 MacBook, which doesn't have CUDA installed. Is there a way to set the environment variable depending on whether or not CUDA is installed?

The usual way that I would check if CUDA is available (in Linux) is `nvcc --version`. If that returns a valid output, then it's installed. I was thinking of something like:

```
if "nvcc --version":
    export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In a bash script the syntax would be more like this:

```
if nvcc --version
then
  export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
fi
```

or, a little shorter:

```
nvcc --version && export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Both of these test the exit status of the `nvcc --version` command without checking its output for validity.